# Display WooCommerce Order Custom Field In Template (HPOS)

Tags: php, custom-field

Until now, I used this code to display a order custom field value inside a template:

```
<?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'my_custom_field', true ) ); ?>
```

When enabling HPOS as the only option, this code no longer works.

I tried:

`<?php echo esc_html( $order->get_billing_my_custom_field() ); ?>` ,

but I keep getting this error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method

Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\Overrides\Order::get...

Answer (score 0):

Use `$order->get_meta('my_custom_field')` instead.